# how to get an element using id on testcafe

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have this HTML code

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Username</label
    ><input
      class="form-control"
      type="text"
      id="username"
      name="username"
      value=""
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Password</label
    ><input
      class="form-control"
      type="password"
      id="password"
      name="password"
      value=""
   />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="">Login</button>
</form>
```

and I have this testcafe code to test this page

```
import { Selector } from "testcafe";
fixture("First Test").page("http://localhost:3000/login");

test("Login Test", async t => {
  const username = await Selector("#username");
  const password = await Selector("#password");
  const loginButton = await Selector("login-button");
  await t
    .typeText(username, "test.email@gmail.com")
    .typeText(password, "testpassword")
    .click(loginButton);
});
```

the issue is am getting this error

```
 × Login Test

  1) The specified selector does not match any element in the DOM tree.

   > | Selector('#username')
```

I know this is a very simple thing but for some reason it's not working for me I saw the documentation and am trying what's in the documentation but I can't seem to get the element using the id. am new to testcafe so please help me out.

Comment: Is the code you posted the exact same as what you're running? Username and password are found/working correctly for me.

Comment: so i looked at the error again and the issue i thing is when i try to add a text to it. At this point of the code
    
   "   await t.typeText(username, "test.email@gmail.com")   "

Comment: Hmm yeah I copied your example and it's working fine on my end. If you go to `http://localhost:3000/login` manually you can see the fields and the submit button as expected?

Answer (score 0):

That also happend to me, I know is not the better way to solve it but it worked for me. This is what I use:

`const input = Selector('input').withAttribute('id','idValue')`

Hope that this works also for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add `await` while creating a variable for the selector

```
fixture("First Test").page("http://localhost:3000/login");

test("Login Test", async t => {
  const username = Selector("#username");
  const password = Selector("#password");
  const loginButton = Selector("login-button");
  await t
    .typeText(username, "test.email@gmail.com")
    .typeText(password, "testpassword")
    .click(loginButton);
});
```